# Adjusting confidence interval of estimator by efficiency

Tags: confidence-interval, estimators, efficiency, rayleigh-distribution

*Summary:* If we have an unbiased MLE $\widehat{\sigma_1}$ of an exponential distribution parameter, and the confidence intervals for its estimates are given by the $\chi^2$ distribution; and we find another unbiased estimator $\widehat{\sigma_2}$ with known relative efficiency to the first; do we have an expression for confidence intervals on the second estimator?

My understanding of relative efficiency (RE) on i.i.d. samples is that RE = $\frac{\mathrm{Var}(\widehat{\sigma_1})}{\mathrm{Var}(\widehat{\sigma_2})} = \frac{n_1}{n_2}$ – meaning that the relative efficiency expresses the relative sample size of the second estimator needed to match the variance of the first.  I.e., we should get the same confidence in $\widehat{\sigma_2}$ with $RE \times n_1$ as we have estimating $\widehat{\sigma_1}$ with $n_1$ samples.  However, monte carlo simulations on a specific example show this is not the case!

---

$Z \sim \mathrm{Rayleigh}(\sigma)$.  The following is an unbiased MLE for $\sigma$ (where *c<sub>G</sub>* is a bias correction term [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Parameter_estimation)):

$$\hat{\sigma}=c_G(n) \sqrt{\frac{\sum^n z_i^2}{2(n-1)}},$$

and since $\sum^n z_i^2 \sim \chi_{2(n-1)}^2,$ we can get confidence bounds on $\hat{\sigma}$ using the quantile function of the $\chi^2$ distribution.  I have verified all of this with simulations.

Now I have found another unbiased estimator $\widehat{\sigma^\ast}$ based on order statistics $z_{(m)}$.  For example: When $n=10$ then $\sum z^2 \approx az^2_{(6)}+bz^2_{(9)}$ for particular coefficients of *a* and *b*.

Simulation confirms what [literature](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1266424) says about the efficiency of this estimator: E.g., for $n=10$ the relative efficiency RE =  $\frac{\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\sigma})}{\mathrm{Var}(\widehat{\sigma^\ast})} \approx$ 87%, which is confirmed by verifying $\frac{\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\sigma}, n=9)}{\mathrm{Var}(\widehat{\sigma^\ast}, n=10)} \approx 1$.

Given all of the above, is there any expression for the confidence bounds on $\widehat{\sigma^\ast}$ for $n=10$?  Based on the definition of RE, I expected that the confidence intervals on $\widehat{\sigma^\ast}$ should be given by $\chi_{2(87\% n-1)}^2$.  However when I simulate this I find that the 95% confidence level is less than the true parameter 2.1% of the time, so too pessimistic.  (The simulation on the optimal $\hat{\sigma}$ shows 95% level less than true parameter 5.0% of the time, as expected.)

Thinking that the problem might be that I'm looking at the square root, I tried $\chi_{2(\sqrt{87\%} n-1)}^2$, but that gave 95% confidence level less than true parameter 3.8% of the time, so it's still too pessimistic.  Meanwhile, using the same confidence formula as for $\hat{\sigma}$ gives 95% confidence level less than true parameter 6.1% of the time, so too optimistic.